# How to select high frequency rectifier capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, rectifier, full-bridge

Can I use aluminium electrolytic capacitor after a full bridge rectifier?

My operation frequency is 200 kHz with output voltage of 100 V.

Based on this paper: "Analysis and Design of Load-Independent Output Current or Output Voltage of a Three-Coil Wireless Power Transfer System", the author has used 940 micro farad output capacitor, which is confusing for me also.

[image]

Based on the specifications of the following paper I = 4 A, F = 200 Khz, by assuming Vpp = 1V and using the formula C = I / 2 x f x Vpp, I get C = 10 µF

Please correct me I have miscalculated.

However my calculation  is pretty different as can been seen from the value shown in the mentioned paper. Since this paper is IEEE transaction paper I have decided to trust it and use 940 uF capacitor after full bridge rectifier.

As far as I know film capacitor have very good performance in high frequency application however a big size of DC film capactitor (940 uF) is very costly.

Can I use an electrolytic capacitor instead?

I believe aluminium electrolytic capacitors vary significantly with increasing frequency. I have confusion in selection of polarized filter capacitor.

What other type of capacitor is suitable?

Comment: Show us your calculation. It sounds like you're off by several orders of magnitude. Or are you really drawing hundreds of amps through this circuit?

Comment: The capacitance needed is related to the current. What current do you need?

Comment: I estimate he's got an output current of circa 400 amps and this does sound extremely far-fetched.

Comment: Show relevant design details and  datasheet links  1mF 160V is <$3 (1k) EKMQ161VSN102MP40S which is about 1mOhm at 2f

Comment: Can you show your circuit or block diagram? Is this proposed capacitor an input filter or an output filter?

Comment: _"Can I use electrolytic capacitor instead?"_ Depends. Which make and model? What does the datasheet say?

Comment: There is an exellent tool on this site to draw your schematic.  Use it so we can see what your trying to do.  Also how did you calculate capacitor value?

Comment: @DaveTweed Thank you so much for all the answers. really appreciated.This is my first time asking question in this website and unfortunately i do not know how can i share the circuit.

Comment: You can either enter your schematic directly (while editing your post, hit ctrl-M) or if you already have an image of it, you can upload that (ctrl-G).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I have updated the circuit diagram. I would be appreciated if once again help me. Thank you so much

Comment: @WarrenHill Thank you Very much for your response, I have edited the question and updated the circuit diagram together with the calculation. really appreciated your help.

Answer (score 1):

If your concerned about losses, then a low ESR capacitor would be best. The other problem is heating, which in most cases is minimal, but for some electrolytics esr over lifetime this can create problems. Tantalum caps need to be derated for voltage. You can also put an electrolytic and ceramic in parallel to get the low esr and high capacitance.

[image]
Source: https://www.murata.com/en-sg/products/emiconfun/capacitor/2011/04/14/en-20110414-p1